# Firebase: Error changing password: Error: Limits exceeded

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a web app with Firebase and yesterday a user made too many attempts when trying to log in. This caused an error and ofcourse this is to prevent abuse and bulk/rainbow password attacks.

The error is: Error changing password: Error: Limits exceeded.(…), in the console.

However, even when the user tries to reset the password via the Firebase.resetPassword() and Firebase.changePassword() functions, he still gets the same error. It seems that the account is blocked and he is not able to reset his password.

Is there a way for me as an admin to reset this error, so that he can change his password without getting the same error over and over again?

Comment: i am having the same problem, did you figure it out? I am using legacy login rather then the new Firebase V3 API's

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm still trying to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Change your test email.

If you try a lot of time with the same email, Firebase send this error:

`"{"error":{"code":400,"message":"RESET_PASSWORD_EXCEED_LIMIT","errors":[{"message":"RESET_PASSWORD_EXCEED_LIMIT","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}}"`

Comment: It is NOT "with the same email", it is a global quota: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits (150 e-mails per day for reset password on spark plan)